# existing project in the same solution but can't debug it

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, dll, nullreferenceexception

I have a `dll` . i add this `dll` as existing project to my web application ,so i can trace the code in it , i put a break point but it never hit this break point at all .

---

```
affectedrows = DBUtilities.UpdateEntityWithTrans("aaa", ParamDictionary, KeyDictionary, DAL_Helper);
```

this line of code throw null reference exception and when i click f11 to enter this class which exist in the `dll` i added before to the solution , It doesn't enter this class to trace the exception.

Comment: Did you also add the PDB debug symbols?

Comment: i added it as existing project(source code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes happens. You add a reference to a project and you have still the reference at the compiled DLL. Please look at your project references list.

Answer (score 2):

You can't debug into lines of code for a referenced .dll, since it's compiled code. You'll need to add an actual source code project if you want to debug into it.

Comment: yeah and this what i did . adding the source code of `dll` as existing project.

Comment: Is visual studio still linking to the .dll instead of the compiled project? Looks like it's not quite linking up correctly.

Comment: But you need to also remove the reference to the dll and reference the project instead.

Comment: i build the project i added and add reference to my main project from the `dll` result from this building